# Database query using Grouping Sets

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle and SQL Developer. I have downloaded schema Sales History and need to do some queries with it. I'm working with table PRODUCTS. As an user I need the sum of PROD_LIST_PRICE per PROD_CATEGORY,  PROD_SUBCATEGORY,  SUPPLIER_ID and also the sum per PROD_CATEGORY. I need to provide solution by GROUPING SETS. I do something like this, but seems that it's quite wrong:

```
WITH ds as(
  SELECT prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id, sum(prod_list_price) sum_all,
GROUPING_ID (prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id) group_id
FROM products
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS (
                (prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id), ()
                )
)
SELECT decode ( GROUPING (prod_category), 1, 'Total', 0, prod_category) cat,
SUM(prod_list_price) sum_prod
FROM ds
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS( (prod_category), ())
ORDER BY prod_category;
```

Maybe I don't understand correctly the conditions. How can I fix this query or modify to do exactly what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't run in its current form

```
SQL> WITH ds as(
  2    SELECT prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id, sum(prod_list_price) sum_all,
  3  GROUPING_ID (prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id) group_id
  4  FROM sh.products
  5  GROUP BY
  6  GROUPING SETS (
  7                  (prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id), ()
  8                  )
  9  )
 10  SELECT decode ( GROUPING (prod_category), 1, 'Total', 0, prod_category) cat,
 11  SUM(prod_list_price) sum_prod
 12  FROM ds
 13  GROUP BY
 14  GROUPING SETS( (prod_category), ())
 15  ORDER BY prod_category;
SUM(prod_list_price) sum_prod
    *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00904: "PROD_LIST_PRICE": invalid identifier
```

but grouping sets is about letting you pick exactly what levels of subtotals you want to do, so its rare to need anything more than a single specification.

If I'm reading your requirements correctly

*I need the sum of PROD_LIST_PRICE per PROD_CATEGORY, PROD_SUBCATEGORY, SUPPLIER_ID and also the sum per PROD_CATEGORY*

the following should do it

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    prod_category,
  3    prod_subcategory,
  4    supplier_id,
  5    sum(prod_list_price) tot,
  6    GROUPING_ID (prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id) group_id
  7  FROM sh.products
  8  GROUP BY
  9  GROUPING SETS (
 10                  (prod_category, prod_subcategory, supplier_id),
 11                  (prod_category)
 12                  );

PROD_CATEGORY                                      PROD_SUBCATEGORY                                   SUPPLIER_ID        TOT   GROUP_ID
-------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------
Photo                                              Cameras                                                      1     899.99          0
Photo                                              Camcorders                                                   1    1099.99          0
Photo                                              Camera Media                                                 1     155.97          0
Photo                                              Camera Batteries                                             1     145.95          0
Photo                                                                                                                 2301.9          3
Hardware                                           Desktop PCs                                                  1     999.99          0
Hardware                                           Portable PCs                                                 1    1299.99          0
Hardware                                                                                                             2299.98          3
Electronics                                        Home Audio                                                   1    1099.98          0
Electronics                                        Y Box Games                                                  1     152.92          0
Electronics                                        Game Consoles                                                1     299.99          0
Electronics                                        Y Box Accessories                                            1      28.98          0
Electronics                                                                                                          1581.87          3
Software/Other                                     Accessories                                                  1     108.95          0
Software/Other                                     Documentation                                                1     269.94          0
Software/Other                                     Recordable CDs                                               1      86.93          0
Software/Other                                     Operating Systems                                            1     199.99          0
Software/Other                                     Bulk Pack Diskettes                                          1      44.98          0
Software/Other                                     Recordable DVD Discs                                         1     105.95          0
Software/Other                                                                                                        816.74          3
Peripherals and Accessories                        CD-ROM                                                       1     254.94          0
Peripherals and Accessories                        Memory                                                       1     262.98          0
Peripherals and Accessories                        Monitors                                                     1    1899.98          0
Peripherals and Accessories                        Modems/Fax                                                   1      90.98          0
Peripherals and Accessories                        Accessories                                                  1     189.95          0
Peripherals and Accessories                        Printer Supplies                                             1     347.96          0
Peripherals and Accessories                                                                                          3046.79          3
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful! Can you give me advice how to receive the same result with ROLLUP and CUBE?

Comment: ROLLUP and CUBE will give you additional levels of subtotals, so all you need to do is add "HAVING GROUPING_ID(...) in (....)" to pick the ones you wqant